# Random walk with 3 values

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-walk, characteristic-functions

I have the following question:

> Consider a one-dimensional random walk with step size $L$, where the
> probability of walking to the right is $1/4$, left is $1/4$, and
> staying where it is $1/2$. Suppose the walker starts from $x=0$.
>
> 1. Obtain the distribution of finding the walker at position $x=nL$ after $N$ steps.
> 2. Get the continuous probability to find the walker at an x position in the time $T=N\tau$, for $N$ too large.
> 3. Get the characteristic function for this continuous function from the previous item.

The first, I think that is similar to [this question of StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501950/one-dimensional-random-walk-with-possibility-to-stand-still). So I found the following:

$$ P_{N}\left(x\right) =\sum_{s=0}^{N-n}\frac{N!}{\left(N-s-r\right)!s!r!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2N-s} $$
Where $r$, $s$ is the probability to go to the right and stay, respectively. So we have some ways to end in the position $x$, and the "options" that $s$ can assume change between $s=0$ (where $n=l-r$) and $s=N-n$ (where $r=n,l=0$).

But the second question, remember me about CTRW (continuous-time random walk):
$$P\left(x,T\right)=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}P\left(N,T\right)P_{N}\left(x\right)$$

But we have a deterministic relationship. I know that in a time $t=T$ we have  $N=\frac{T}{\tau}$ steps. So I can't see another consequence than just know what is the value of $N$ in every $T$. And the third I don't know how to proceed. So I would ask for some tip.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: This is only a hint / tips, not a full solution**

The probability of ending at $x=nL$ after $N$ steps is given by the coefficient of $y^{n}$ from the expression $\left(\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot y\right)^{N}$ or we can write the following:

$$
\begin{align}
P_{N}(n)&=\left[y^{n}\right]\phantom{x} \left(\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot y\right)^{N}\\
\\
&=\left[y^{n}\right]\phantom{x}\frac{1}{4^{N}}\cdot\frac{1}{y^{N}}\cdot\left(1+2y+y^{2}\right)^{N}\\
\\
&=\left[y^{n}\right]\phantom{x}\frac{1}{4^{N}}\cdot\frac{1}{y^{N}}\cdot\left(y+1\right)^{2N}\\
\\
&=\left[y^{N+n}\right]\phantom{x}\frac{1}{4^{N}}\cdot\left(y+1\right)^{2N}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{4^{N}}\cdot\binom{2N}{N+n}
\end{align}
$$

Now that we have a simple expression, I believe you can finish the rest by yourself

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused with this notation. What is y?

Comment: The power of the $y$ represent our position. We start with $y^{0}$ and then at each step we have $\frac{1}{4}$ probability of going to the left represented by $\frac{1}{4}\cdot y^{-1}$, $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of staying still represented by $\frac{1}{2}\cdot y^{0}$, and probability $\frac{1}{4}$ of going to the right represented by $\frac{1}{4}\cdot y^{1}$. Notice that the coefficients are probabilities. Now if we take $N$ steps, we multiply with that equation to the power of $N$ like in the solution above

Comment: @JhordanSilveiradeBorba the $y$ itself is not important.